# Professional Printer for Mass-Producing A4 Brochures?

Tags: printer, printing

The company I work for is looking at printing tens of thousands of high-quality A4 brochures, and we want to explore the possibilities of buying some printer(s) and producing them in-house, which may work out better for us in the long-run (several re-prints down the line).

Should we consider buying a high-quality printer, or should we hire a professional printing service?

Many thanks.

Comment: Buying recommendations are off-topic as you can read in the [FAQ].

Comment: Since no one will ultimately give him a buying recommendation, but rather will just try to steer him away from his thought process, I do not recommend closure.

Comment: @KCotreau He is specifically asking for a good printer. If the answers go in a different direction, fair enough, but that still doesn't change the question ("I have 10.000 Pounds, what is the best printer?").

Comment: @slhck I edited the question to take out the specific request since I thought the question was good otherwise.

Comment: Way cheaper to outsource this to a local print shop.

Comment: You could buy the kit but then you must factor in its care and, maintenance + the cost of having it idle for long periods of time. Print shops aim to have their repro kit running contiguously for as much of the time as possible in order to make it pay for itself. Unless you can think of another income stream for your shiny, expensive in-house printing facilities it will be much cheaper to have someone else do the work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such quantities are really something you should put into the hands of a specialist printing service, who will have the equipment and knowledge to ensure the product you receive is of a satisfactory quality.

That said, if you do want to do it in house, I'd personally recommend speaking to a printer vendor like HP directly and asking what solutions they can provide for your task, and make sure to mention stapling! The outlay wont be cheap but if it means saving in the long run then go for it!

Answer (score 1):

For brochures, while you can get very good results with a standard high-quality printer for what you are looking to spend, you likely will not get the same results as a professional printer, and you may not be totally pleased with the results (read, you wasted a lot of money). For brochures, most smaller print shops don't even do them themselves, and send them out to places that have equipment costing 100's of thousands of dollars. They don't use standard printers to get the best results.

Farm it out.

http://www.brochuremonster.com/printing/printing.php (go to the section on commercial printers).